# Why does this number value in a string change to a string when between other strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a codewars problem but do not understand why this particular thing is happening. 
** edit - the codewars problem asks that you use no existing array or object prototype methods.
I'm iterating over an array of numbers and numbers as strings, and if 0 or "0" placing them at the end. I've placed a 0 at the end after a "0", and it remains an int, but when i place another "0" after it it turns into a string. Here's the code:

```
function removeZeros(array) {
    let z = array.length - 1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
        console.log(array);
        if (array[i] === 0 || array[i] === '0') {
            const x = array[i];

            for (let j = i; j <= z; j++) {
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
            }
            array[array.length - 1] = x;
            z -= 1;
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(removeZeros([1, '0', 5, 0, '5', 52, '0', 7, 0, '3', 1]));
```

and in the console here is the array for the step in question:

```
[
  1, 5, '5', 52, '0',
  7, 0, '3', 1,  '0',
  0
]
[
  1,   5,   '5', 52,  7,
  0,   '3', 1,   '0', '0',
  '0'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep shifting a smaller prefix of the array, but always stuff the 0 (of either type) into the last position, so that the earlier 0's don't actually get shifted.  Instead, you could move the 0 to the end of the prefix you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I dont really understand you i'm afraid, i'm still new to coding. I forgot to mention that the codewars problem asks that you do not use any existing array or object protoptype methods.  I believe I am moving all the values in the array forward 1 spot, and then replacing the last one, as indicated in the console when printing the array. It's only when i sandwich the int between the two strings it changes to a string.

Comment: You are not shifting correctly, but it is hard to see because you have the same value appearing multiple times.  "Sandwiching" has nothing to do with it.